# How to define baseURL based on ENVIRONMENT in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Upgraded from CodeIgniter 3 to CodeIgniter 4 and at the begining I found a problem I cannot resolve.
In CI3 I had a switch statement in `application/config/config.php` to set the `$config['base_url']`.
It's like

```
$localFolder = "localfolder";

switch (ENVIRONMENT) {
    case 'development':
        $config['base_url'] = "http://$localFolder.loc";
        break;

    default:
        $config['base_url'] = "http://testserver.com/$localFolder";
        break;
}
```

But in CI4 the `app/Config/App.php` is now a class and I haven't figured out how could I define the `public $baseURL = "samplefolder";` based on the `ENVIRONMENT` variable.

Calling a function immediately not working:

```
public $baseURL = (function(){
        switch (ENVIRONMENT) {
            case 'development':
                $this->baseURL = "http://$localFolder.loc";
                break;

            default:
                $this->baseURL = "http://testserver.com/$localFolder";
                break;
        }
    })();
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations
```

Also, calling the function after declaring with `$this->` produces error:

```
public $baseURL = "";

public function baseURL($localFolder)
    {
        switch (ENVIRONMENT) {
            case 'development':
                $this->baseURL = "http://$localFolder.loc";
                break;

            default:
                $this->baseURL = "http://testserver.com/$localFolder";
                break;
        }
    }

$this->baseURL("localfolder");
```

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question and as I haven't yet looked into doing something similar for my own sites, now is as good as time as any to look into this...

This isn't the greatest of solutions but something to consider.

You could add (append) the following to you App.php to contain...

```
    protected $localFolder = 'localfolder';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setBaseUrl(); // Set the Base URL
    }

    protected function setBaseUrl() {
        switch ($_ENV['CI_ENVIRONMENT']) {
            case 'development':
                $this->baseURL = "http://$this->localFolder.loc";
                break;
            default:
                $this->baseURL = "http://testserver.com/$this->localFolder";
                break;
        }
    }
} // End of APP Class
```

So changing your CI_ENVIRONMENT Value in your .env file will switch your $baseURL.

**A Better way**

You might be better off setting your $localFolder as a ENV value so you can control this from the one location.

LOCAL_FOLDER = 'localfolder'

**Within your .env file**

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# ENVIRONMENT
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# CI_ENVIRONMENT = production
CI_ENVIRONMENT = development
LOCAL_FOLDER = 'localfolder'
```

Then the setBaseUrl method would become

```
protected function setBaseUrl() {
    switch ($_ENV['CI_ENVIRONMENT']) {
        case 'development':
            $this->baseURL = "http://{$_ENV['LOCAL_FOLDER']}.loc";
                break;
        default:
            $this->baseURL = "http://testserver.com/{$_ENV['LOCAL_FOLDER']}";
                break;
    }
}
```

Hoepfully that gives you a few ideas.

Answer (score 4):

A better practice would be to have one unique .env file for each of your environment. Then set your conf into those .env files.
For example, you could have a .env file like this :

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# ENVIRONMENT
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

CI_ENVIRONMENT = development

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# APP
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

app.baseURL = 'http://localfolder.loc'
```

And an other with `app.baseURL = 'http://testserver.com/localfolder'`.

Go check CI4 documentation about it : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/configuration.html#handling-different-environments

Comment: Yes, probably for larger projects this would be my choice also, but many times I have daily small projects and I need to have a base CI4 base template that is as flexible as I can make to speed up these small projects

Comment: How does this work exactly? If I have a single project, but multiple environments (dev and prod), and I move the project between the environments, I would expect the project to work without additional modification. Assuming I can only have one `.env` file in the project folder, this won't help. [Environments in CI3](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html#environments) was more dynamic. I could create a custom folder in the config folder and store the environment-specific settings there. I'm trying to do the same in CI4.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do this, is through [Registrars](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/configuration.html#registrars)

The benefit of this approach is that you can overwrite any of the configurations in one place. You simply create a Config/Registrar.php file, and overwrite configurations like this:

```
namespace Config;

class Registrar
{
    public static function App(): array {
        return [
            'production' => ['baseURL' => 'https://example.com'],
            'development' => ['baseURL' => 'https://dev.example.com']
        ][$_ENV['CI_ENVIRONMENT']];
    }
}
```